# Data Transfer from gcp cloud storage to bigquery - log says success but no data in bigquery table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

We are using Google cloud data transfer option from cloud storage to bigquery - transfer job runs every day at certain time and transfers a csv file from storage to bigquery.
Transfer log says success and gives transfer row number as well.But destination table has no data.
Can someone please help here ?

Comment: Did you check the data in the preview section or by performing a query?

Comment: Yes it don't have

Comment: 1) Are you following any tutorial? 2)when is the last modification of your file when invoking the export? 3)can you share enough info so that we can try to reproduce your issue please

Comment: 1) from one script we create file with some data in storage(which fallows the condition of being 60 mins old).We have configured a data transfer from storage to big-query by specifying bigquery data set name ,table name and storage file path. 2) This transfer is not from any script , it is form transfer option in https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery/transfers. 3)Logs says 1 job success and gives number of rows transferred also(which is around 1.6L) but table has no data.(I have only this job running on that table)

Comment: @PriyankaKambari in this case I would reccommend you to open a case with Google Cloud Platform Support and share with them your resource name